# Importing project from github to eclipse error

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I have some troubles with importing my project (default android project) from github to eclipse.
Steps that I made:

1. Click import
2. Select Git => Projects from git => url
3. Paste https://github.com/ivanbordyug/TestProject.git to URL => Click next
4. Select maser brunch => click next
5. Select directory => click next
6. Recieve objects => click next
7. And in Import project I see message "No project found"

But when I import "Excisting code" from folder where imported files are stored, all is OK. Pls, help me with this, because I dont know what is wrong.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to:

- clone locally the repo through a console (`git clone`)
- Then import that project through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by doing the following -

1. If it is a maven project in eclipse, import it as a maven project (or what ever project type).
2. Then delete the project from eclipse.
3. Now import it again as a git project, it wont show "No project found" now, and will be imported successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of repository then you can resolve it by following simple steps.
The eclipse is giving this error because it is trying to find *.project* and *.classpath* files in the project you are importing from git. If it is not found it gives error as no project found to import.

**Steps to Resolve**

1. open .gitignore file of your project
2. delete entry of *.project* and *.classpath*
3. push it to repository
4. now anyone can pull it and the error will be gone.